# What is the difference between ~아/어 가다/오다 and ~아/어지다 and ~게 되다?

Tags: grammar

Both grammar constructs express a change from at some point of the time. For example,

> 급속한 경제 성장으로 인해 사람들의 가치관도 변해 왔다.

> 급속한 경제 성장으로 인해 사람들의 가치관도 변해졌다.

Or

> 이번 정부의 정책 덕분에 침체된 지역 경제가 드디어 발전해 갈 것입니다.

> 이번 정부의 정책 덕분에 침체된 지역 경제가 드디어 발전하게 될 것입니다.

But I’m not sure about the difference between two, and when to use the one grammar over the other.

Comment: Where did you obtain those sentences? 변하다 is sort of a *passive* verb because of its meaning (무엇이 다른 것이 **되거나** 혹은 다른 성질로 **달라지다**), so 변했다 or 변하였다 should be used instead of 변해졌다. The construction "드디어 ...ㄹ 것입니다" sounds a bit awkward here; in addition, 침체된 경제가 발전하다 is *not* a collocation. We should come up with better examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-아/어 가다/오다 must indicate explicitly that something is *continual*; however, -아지다/어지다 and -게 되다 themselves do not. For the latter, the *context* gives a hint on whether it is continual. There are adverbs, such as 점점, 점차, and 계속, and postpositions, such as 부터 and 까지, which are used to express it explicitly. In addition, it is *not* necessary to use -고 있다 to say that something is continuing to happen; for example, the present simple tense in Korean can be used as the present simple and progressive tenses in English.

Perhaps, it is helpful to know the definitions of them.

오다: (**주로 동사 뒤에서 ‘-어 오다’ 구성으로 쓰여**) 앞말이 뜻하는 행동이나 상태가 말하는 이 또는 말하는 이가 정하는 **기준점으로 가까워지면서 계속 진행됨**을 나타내는 말.

가다: (**주로 동사 뒤에서 ‘-어 가다’ 구성으로 쓰여**) 말하는 이, 또는 말하는 이가 정하는 어떤 **기준점에서 멀어지면서** 앞말이 뜻하는 행동이나 상태가 **계속 진행됨**을 나타내는 말.

되다 after -게:

1. 어떤 사물이나 현상이 생겨나거나 만들어지다
2. 일이 잘 이루어지다
3. 작물 따위가 잘 자라다
4. 어떤 사물이 제 기능을 다 하거나 수명이 다하다
5. 어떤 **상황이나 사태에 이르다**
6. 운명으로 결정되거나 규칙, 절차 따위로 정해지다.

-어지다/아지다:

1. (동사 뒤에서) 남의 힘에 의하여 앞말이 뜻하는 행동을 입음을 나타내는 말
2. (동사 뒤에서) 앞말이 뜻하는 대로 하게 됨을 나타내는 말
3. (**형용사 뒤에서**) 앞말이 뜻하는 **상태로 됨**을 나타내는 말

**계속** is mentioned in the definitions of -어/아 오다 and -어/아 가다 only. You should also note that these two are different in that it is coming to a point for 오다 whereas it is going away from a point for 가다. -게 되다 and -아지다/어지다 have several definitions other than the one relating to the state and situation. They are different at some points: (1) To mention the change, an adjective (*not* a verb) is used with -아지다/어지다 ("adj. + -아지다/어지다" forms a verb), while a verb is usually used with -게 되다 (It does not mean that you cannot use "adj. + -게 되다," but in a number of cases, "adj. + -게" forms an adverb *irrelevant* to the change); (2) -게 되다 places more emphasis on external influence whereas -아지다/어지다 mainly on spontaneity. Another point you should know is that -아지다/어지다 can come before -어 오다/가다 and -게 되다.

I left a comment about a few but important problems with your example sentences, so I will give you better examples here.

- 그 소식에 가슴이 아파 왔다. (adj. + -아 오다)
- 그 소식에 가슴이 아파져 왔다. (adj. + -아지다 + -어 오다) (Note: Although 아파 왔다 sounds more natural and even the standard dictionary uses 아파 오다, 아파져 is logically better than 아파 here because -아/어 오다 tends to be used with a verb rather than an adjective.)
- 그 소식에 가슴이 아파졌다. (adj. + -아지다)
- 시간이 갈수록 어깨는 점점 더 아파 갔다. (adj. + -아 가다)
- 시간이 갈수록 어깨는 점점 더 아파 왔다. (adj. + -아 오다)
- 시간이 갈수록 어깨는 점점 더 아파졌다. (adj. + -아지다)
- 갑자기 숨이 가빠 왔다. (adj. + -아 오다)
- 갑자기 숨이 가빠졌다. (adj. + -아지다)
- 아들이 상경한 지 나흘이 되어 가는데 감감무소식이다. (v. + -어 가다)
- 아들이 상경한 지 나흘이 되어 오는데 감감무소식이다. (v. + -어 오다)
- 밥을 다 먹어 간다. (v. + -어 가다) (Note: Here, you *cannot* use 온다 instead of 간다.)
- 우리가 아무런 조치를 취하지 않으면 사태가 걷잡을 수 없을 정도로 커지게 된다. (adj. + -어지다 + -게 되다)
- 우리가 아무런 조치를 취하지 않으면 사태가 걷잡을 수 없을 정도로 커진다. (adj. + -어지다)
- 내가 이 일을 맡게 되었다. (v. + -게 되다)
- 유류비 인상이 불가피하게 되었다. (adj. + -게 되다)

Comment: Thanks for the answer and sorry that the example sentences on my question are what I came up with.